# How to deserialize a json string containing property type in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I am receiving this weird `Json` string from an API, that also contains the schema within it. I am trying to convert it to a simple model and I am not being able to do it because of this schema structure.

The `Json` sample is:

```
[{
"key":null,
"value":{"session_id":{"string":"xxxxx"},
"title_id_type":{"string":"server"},
"event_name":{"string":"achievement"},
"event_type":{"string":"server"},
"event_step":{"int":8},
"country":{"string":"US"},
"event_params":{"map":{"cdur":"416","gdur":"416","sdur":"416","tdur":"0","type":"challenge","percent":"100","status":"expired"}},
"device_id_map":{"map":{}},
"experiment_id_list":{"array":[]}
]}
```

I would expect this model to be:

```
public class MyModel
{
   [JsonProperty("session_id")]
   public string SessionId {get;set;}
   [JsonProperty("title_id_type")]
   public string TitleIdType{get;set;}
   [JsonProperty("event_step")]
   public int EventStep {get;set;}
   ...
}
```

So far, my tests resulted in objects where those `string` and `int` are property names, messing up the whole thing.

How could I deserialize such `Json` in a clean way? I am using **.NET Core 5** and **Newtonsoft.Json** but no restrictions for a new library.

Comment: Use a custom converter??? [Custom Json Converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0)

Comment: Are you using Json.NET or System.Text.Json?  You've implied System.Text.Json with .NET Core 5, but the `[JsonProperty]` attribute comes from Json.NET.

Comment: @DavidL Currently `Newtonsoft.Json` but no restrictions to change it.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is unknown how deep the nested properties might go and it is also unknown what types need to be handled, the simplest option is to create a custom converter that you apply to each property that contains a schema object:

```
public class KeyValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public class KeyValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JObject.Load(reader);

        if (!token.HasValues)
            throw new Exception("KeyValueConverter requires one property per target object");

        if (token.Values().Count() > 1)
            throw new Exception("KeyValueConverter does not support multiple properties per target object");
            
        var prop = token.First.ToObject<JProperty>();
        return prop.Value.ToObject(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can then apply it to each property that will contain a schema object and based on the type of the target property, it will write the value as the correct target type.

```
var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, MyModel>>>(json);

public class MyModel
{
    [JsonProperty("session_id")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(KeyValueConverter))]
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("title_id_type")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(KeyValueConverter))]
    public string TitleIdType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("event_step")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(KeyValueConverter))]
    public int EventStep { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("event_params")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(KeyValueConverter))]
    public Dictionary<string, object> EventParams { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("experiment_id_list")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(KeyValueConverter))]
    public List<object> ExperimentIdList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What would be the `switch case` for the type `map` in the schema? I simplified the sample, but lots of them are of type `map`.

Comment: @TiagoBrenck can you give an example of the JSON object? Most likely the target type would be a dictionary and/or KeyValuePair

Comment: Done, I edited the json. I will try with `Dictionary` then.

Comment: @TiagoBrenck I updated and simplified my answer based on your updated JSON.  It is probably easier to let the target type of your model drive serialization behavior, rather than coercing it based on the schema key.  I added a dictionary and List<object> example.

Comment: The converter is returning this error in the `Load(reader)` part: `Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.`

Comment: It's because your input json is different than the original example.  You'd need to use something like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, MyModel>>>(json);` to mirror it. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its because model does not have definition for the json objects inside object root. I suppose that you are usign System.Text or other, anyway when this libreries read {} inside an string with json format they interpret that it would be deserialize like other class. So your model would have to have propierties with type of the class that have definitions for keys inside {}.

I've copied your json and paste like classes and get something like this

```
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public object key { get; set; }
        public Value value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public Session_Id session_id { get; set; }
        public Title_Id_Type title_id_type { get; set; }
        public Event_Name event_name { get; set; }
        public Event_Type event_type { get; set; }
        public Event_Step event_step { get; set; }
        public Country country { get; set; }
        public Event_Params event_params { get; set; }
        public Device_Id_Map device_id_map { get; set; }
        public Experiment_Id_List experiment_id_list { get; set; }
    }

    public class Session_Id
    {
        public string _string { get; set; }
    }

    public class Title_Id_Type
    {
        public string _string { get; set; }
    }

    public class Event_Name
    {
        public string _string { get; set; }
    }

    public class Event_Type
    {
        public string _string { get; set; }
    }

    public class Event_Step
    {
        public int _int { get; set; }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public string _string { get; set; }
    }

    public class Event_Params
    {
        public Map map { get; set; }
    }

    public class Map
    {
        public string cdur { get; set; }
        public string gdur { get; set; }
        public string sdur { get; set; }
        public string tdur { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string percent { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Device_Id_Map
    {
        public Map1 map { get; set; }
    }

    public class Map1
    {
    }

    public class Experiment_Id_List
    {
        public object[] array { get; set; }
    }
```

So all this classes are needed to deserialize your json string to an object, thats why its better that your string take other format before deserialize by deleting brackets { } or whatever you see convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/), an open source library to manage this conversion with few lines of code

Here is one way to accomplish using this library without type converters

```
string json = @"
[
  {
    ""key"": null,
    ""value"": {
      ""session_id"": { ""string"": ""pFEe0KByL/Df:3170:5"" },
      ""title_id_type"": { ""string"": ""server"" },
      ""event_name"": { ""string"": ""achievement"" },
      ""event_type"": { ""string"": ""server"" },
      ""event_step"": { ""int"": 8 },
      ""country"": { ""string"": ""US"" },
      ""event_params"": {
        ""map"": {
          ""cdur"": ""416"",
          ""gdur"": ""416"",
          ""sdur"": ""416"",
          ""tdur"": ""0"",
          ""type"": ""challenge"",
          ""percent"": ""100"",
          ""status"": ""expired""
        }
      },
      ""device_id_map"": { ""map"": {} },
      ""experiment_id_list"": { ""array"": [""a"", ""b""] },
      ""experiment_id_list1"": { ""array"": [1, 2] },
    }
  }
]";

using (var r = ChoJSONReader<Root1>.LoadText(json)
    .Setup(s => s.BeforeRecordFieldLoad += (o, e) =>
    {
        JObject jo = e.Source as JObject;
        if (jo != null)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName != "value")
            {
                var prop = jo.First.ToObject<JProperty>();
                e.Source = prop.Value;
            }
        }
    })
    )
{
    foreach (var rec in r)
        Console.WriteLine(rec.Dump());
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm author of this library